# Calcular la diferencia en días entre dos fechas con momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Calculé la diferencia de la fecha de termino (dato que viene de la base de datos) menos la fecha actual para sacar cuantos días restantes quedan.

Ya lo hice con momentjs y con javascript sacando los segundos. En ambas formas me hace bien el cálculo.

El problema es que si la fecha de término llega a ser entre el 1 de diciembre y el 31 de enero de cualquier año, me da como resultado `NAN`. Fuera de esas fechas calcula perfecto.

El `for` es porque estoy calculando en una tabla con datos que se van agregando, pero ya probé el código solo, sin el `for` y me da el mismo resultado:

```
<script>
moment.locale('es-mx'); 

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 900000; i++)
{
var myVar = document.getElementById("fecha_termino"+i).value;
var fecha_actual = new Date();
var fecha_inicio = moment(fecha_actual).format("DD-MMMM-YYYY");
var fecha_termino = new Date(myVar)
var fecha_termino = moment(myVar);

console.log(fecha_termino.diff(fecha_inicio, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia');
var dias_restantes = fecha_termino.diff(moment(fecha_inicio), 'days');
var objetivo = document.getElementById('dias_restantes'+i)
objetivo.innerHTML = dias_restantes;
} </script>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). En tu código deberías reproducir exactamente el problema que tienes y no dejarlo abierto a las pruebas. ¿Y si usas en `fecha_inicio` un formato estándar de fechas en vez de uno local? Es decir, `aaaa-mm-dd` en vez de `dd-mm-aaaa`.

Comment: De hecho, en tu código te está saltando una advertencia en la consola de depuración, justo por este motivo, que dice: *Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.*

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar fechas en formato [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) y no locales para evitar confusiones. En este caso particular, además, [te están indicando en la configuración que debes hacerlo así](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> `moment(String);`
>
> When creating a `moment` from a string, **we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats**, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.
>
> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is [**inconsistent**](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

En castellano:

> `moment(String);`
>
> Cuando creamos un `moment` de una cadena de caracteres, **primero comprobamos que coincida con un formato ISO 8601 conocido**, entonces comprobamos si coincide con el formato de fecha y hora RFC 2822 antes de usar como último recurso `new Date(string)` si no se encuentra un formato conocido.
>
> **Advertencia:** El soporte del navegador para analizar cadenas es [**inconsistente**](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Debido a que no existe una especificación sobre qué formatos puede admitir, lo que funciona en algunos navegadores puede que no funcione en otros.

Por ese motivo tu código está lanzando en la consola de depuración la siguiente advertencia:

> *Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date for more info.*

Así que, por ejemplo, las fechas deberías indicarlas en formato: `año-mes-día` o `aaaa-mm-dd`.

Además, tienes muchísimo código innecesario que puedes eliminar:

```js
moment.locale('es-mx');

const myVar = '2022-01-31';
/* Obtenemos un moment de ahora mismo */
const fecha_inicio = moment();
/* Obtenemos un moment de la fecha indicada anteriormente */
const fecha_termino = moment(myVar);

/* Calculamos la diferencia y la mostramos en el documento */
dias_restantes.innerText = fecha_termino.diff(fecha_inicio, 'days');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
Días restantes: <span id="dias_restantes"></span>
```

Por ejemplo, `moment()` puede recibir una fecha en formato de cadena para ser convertida, por lo que no es necesario convertirla previamente con `Date()` antes de pasarla como parámetro.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias convertir los Date a milisegundos y usar calculo basico para sacar los dias de diferencias sin problemas :

```
//usamos la funcion .getTime() para convertir la fecha a milisegundos.
const fecha1 = new Date("2020-01-01T20:02:36.694Z").getTime(); 
const fecha2 = new Date("2019-12-31T20:02:36.694Z").getTime(); 
var result = (fecha1 - fecha2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); //divido la resta de las dos fechas entre 1000milisegundos * 60segundos * 60minutos * 24horas , obteniendo como resultado 1dia de diferencia
console.log(result);
```

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma, pero curiosamente me da el mismo resultado, solo cuando la fecha de termino entra en el mes de diciembre y enero me marca error al calcular los días restantes

Comment: Eh editado mi respuesta usando 2 timestamps uno el 31 de diciembre del 2019 y otro el 1ro de enero del 2020 y aun sigue teniendo el resultado deseado. Buenos dias.